# Are there 2p elements of order p in $\mathbb{Z}_p \times\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know the order of  $\mathbb{Z}_p \times\mathbb{Z}_p$ is $p^2$, that there are $p^2$ elements in the set represented by  $\mathbb{Z}_p \times\mathbb{Z}_p$. Of those elements how many are of order $p$? I'm thinking it is $2p$, since the elements of  $\mathbb{Z}_p \times\mathbb{Z}_p$ are of the form $(a,b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are the elements of order $p$ are of the form $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint:** What is the order of $(1,1)$?

(**Hint 2:** The only possible orders of an element divide $p^2$ and are hence $1$, $p$ or $p^2$. Can any non-identity element have order $1$ or $p^2$?)

Comment: Since it is the identity it has order 1, correct? Okay, so I see why the order of an element divide p^2 has to be 1,p,p^2. Does this mean only the identity element has order 1. That means all other elements have order p and since the total number of elements is p^2, then p^2 - 1 is the number of elements with order p. 

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, every element other than the identity has order $p$, and hence there are $p^2-1$ such elements. However, the identity is $(0,0)$ not $(1,1)$ - indeed, $(1,1)$ is an element with order $p$ and my point was that it is not of the form $(a,0)$ or $(0,b)$ as you suggest in the question. (I assume you're working under addition, not multiplication).